Looking for a letter written by Gauss in which he remarks that he has worked very hard on mathematics
In my memory, I once read a letter that Gauss wrote to a friend or acquaintance in which he remarks something along the following lines---if people worked on mathematics as much as I did, they would be competent mathematicians.  Surely these were not the words, but it was something to that effect.  I have no idea how to find this letter again.  I'm not a student of Gauss, for example.  This was a letter I read by accident some day.
Question. Do you have any idea in which publication I could find this letter again?

Perhaps one of the Wikiquotes for Gauss: "If others would but reflect on mathematical truths as deeply and as continuously as I have, they would make my discoveries."?

The quote comes, without a citation, from E.T. Bell, who is not exactly reliable. Something to this effect is repeated by Dunnington in Gauss, Titan of Science, but not as a quote and also without a source: "It was his custom to tell his friends that if others would meditate as long and as deeply as he did on mathematical truths, they would be able to make his discoveries." See Authenticity of Gauss's Quote "If others reflect on mathematical truths as deeply as I...".

The thought is expressed in Sartorius's 1856 Gauss zum Gedächtniss (see p56 in https://ia800301.us.archive.org/22/items/gaussmemorial00walt/gaussmemorial00walt.pdf  an English translation by CFG's great-granddaughter) w/o citation. "Were other people but willing, he said, to ponder mathematical truths as deeply and continuously as he did, they too...". –

Expressing my gratitude to all of the above.  Thanks very much for the valuable references and pointers.  Very appreciated.
